# ionic.Native error with $cordovaStatusbar

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am migrating from ngCordova to ionic.Native.
I have installed the StatusBar plugin:

```
ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
```

But when I inject it:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaStatusbar)
```

and try to build : `$ ionic run android`, I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaStatusbarProvider <- $cordovaStatusbar
```

Can you help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok in case it can help others:
ngCordova uses :`$cordovaStatusbar`
while ionic.Native uses `$cordovaStatusBar`.

And in case you were using `$cordovaStatusbar.style()` with ngCordova, this function doesn't exist anymore, you need to use : `$cordovaStatusBar.styleLightContent();`